# Video skipping is not allow in chrome and mozilla when video is not buffered (Using Html VideoTag)

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video, video-processing

I am using html video tag.Skipping of video is not working in chrome and Mozilla. Example:- video length is 3 minutes and I want to skip 2 minutes of video and directly want to start playing from 3.5 minutes then its not working in both browser where as it is working in edge and IE.

How we can skip video.

Here is my code:

```
<video id="video" class="family-post-img" preload="auto" autobuffer muted="muted" controls style="display:block;cursor: pointer;width:100%;object-fit: fill;height: 100%;">
<source src="@Model.FileURL" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I want to do skipping of video as youtube as well as buffering.

Comment: How can you start playing from minute 3.5 when video is only 3 minutes long?

Comment: The mp4 must be created (or processed) to enable fast start, and the server must support byte range requests.